# Resolve just one Item in List<Lazy<T>> with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-2, ninject-extensions

**This is my Scenario:**

```
 public class Foo
    {
        private readonly List<Lazy<IAnimal>> _animals;

        public Foo(List<Lazy<IAnimal>> animals )
        {
            _animals = animals;
        }

        public void Bark()
        {
            //Line: *
            var dog = _animals.First(p => p.GetType() == typeof (Dog)).Value;
        }

        Public void Mio()
        {
            //Line: *
            var dog = _animals.First(p => p.GetType() == typeof (Cat)).Value;
        }
    }

    public class Dog:IAnimal
    {
    }

    public class Cat:IAnimal
    {
    }

    public interface IAnimal
    {
    }
```

**Questions:**

Here The list of Animals are Lazily injected into the class Foo.

I want to do something like Line * with `Ninject`. As you may know the problem is that before resolving a class, `GetType()` returns `Null`. So how can I resolve just one of the Items in the list whenever I want?

Can `Ninject` do such a thing at all or I have to change my DI Container?

Comment: Since you're interested in one `Dog` instance in the `Bark` method, why don't you just inject that single `Dog` instance into `Foo`'s constructor?

Comment: So, why not inject a Dog and a Cat? If you have even more of those methods, you might be violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @Steven you know I actually have some buttons on my `MainWindow` which they are responsible to make a sound of an animal (first button for dog, second for cat and so on) the Foo class is actually my `MainWindowViewModel` which I have bound the buttons' `Command` to methods in it. The scenario is actually is much more complex than this sample code. I have used these terminologies just for the sake of simplicity as you know. actually I have heavy tree of classes which I think if I want to resolve them at my composition root, it will affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a chicken and the egg problem: you don't know the type unless you get the value. You can only solve this by adding extra information to the list that is known before hand.

This is a good fit for [Lazy<T, TMetadata>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986615.aspx) which is part of the **System.ComponentModel.Composition** assembly:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private readonly List<Lazy<IAnimal, Type>> _animals;

    public Foo(List<Lazy<IAnimal, Type>> animals)
    {
        _animals = animals;
    }

    public void Bark()
    {
        var dog = _animals.First(p => p.Metadata == typeof(Dog)).Value;
    }
}
```

**Update**

As I said in the comments, I'm no Ninject expert, but most things can be done with a framework, even when there is no built-in support for it. This is what I think your registration would look like. I might have the Ninject syntax wrong, but it would look a bit like this:

```
var list = new List<Lazy<IAnimal, Type>>();

list.Add(new Lazy<IAnimal, Type>(() => kernel.Get<Dog>(), typeof(Dog)));
list.Add(new Lazy<IAnimal, Type>(() => kernel.Get<Pussy>(), typeof(Pussy)));
list.Add(new Lazy<IAnimal, Type>(() => kernel.Get<Horse>(), typeof(Horse)));

kernel.Bind<List<Lazy<IAnimal, Type>>().ToConstant(list);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Steven. But how can I `Bind` that now in my composition root? how can I send the `Metadata`?

Comment: You will have to do this manually. There is no built-in support for this. The only container that has built-in support for Lazy<T, TMetadata> is [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Metadata), but I wouldn't switch just because of this. It should be quite easy to register your collection (although I'm not an Ninject expert).

Comment: Sorry But I don't know how to do it manually? If `Ninject` doesn't support that, so how can I do it?

Comment: I have done it but I faced with an error that it is too long to write it here in the comment. so I delete some unnecessary lines of that to be fit here.

Comment: Ninject.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
Message=Error activating Lazy{IAnimal, Type} using implicit self-binding of Lazy{IAnimal, Type}
Several constructors have the same priority. Please specify the constructor using ToConstructor syntax or add an Inject attribute.
Activation path:
2) Injection of dependency Lazy{IAnimal, Type} into parameter animals of constructor of type Foo
1) Request for Foo
Suggestions:1) Ensure that the implementation type has a public constructor.
2) If you have implemented the Singleton pattern, use a binding with InSingletonScope() instead.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh: Replace `ToInstance` with `ToConstant`.

Comment: Yea I did that. There is no `ToInstance()` method. I changed that `ToConstant()` but I got the error. BTW I want to send a list of animals. which I will choose in runtime to be Dog, Cat or etc.

Comment: Do you think I have to change my DI Container? because I have stuck on this for 2 days. I really don't know how to solve it. HELP! ;)

Comment: Unlikely. Why do you even need `Lazy<T>` in the first place? It's hard for me to reason about this, but might want to reconsider your design. Why don't you create a new question on SO to discuss this partical part of your application. If you want any valuable feedback on the design, please use real class names (and perhaps a bit of background info on what that class does). If you post a link here, I'll try to take a look at it.

Comment: You know your answer is exactly what I was looking for. you understood my question completely. But if I just can find out the reason of the error, I am done. anyway I think it is very difficult to explain all my code with their real names. is that possible to send my whole solution somewhere to be seen by you?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method provided in the System.Linq namespace.

```
var dog = _animals.OfType<Dog>().First();
```

Comment: As I said the type is not determined before resolving. so It can't be done.